# Supply Context to DbMigrator

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, dbmigrator

## How DbMigrator works

I have code that instantiates a new `DbMigrator(new Configuration())`

`Configuration` is a custom extension of `DbMigrationsConfiguration<T>`, where T is `DbContext`

So within `Configuration`, there is a ContextType, which is equal to `<T>`.

When DbMigrator is instantiated, it attempts to create an instance of the `<T>` DbContext.  It will either try to use an Empty Constructor on the `<T>` Context, or it will attempt to look for an implementation of `IDbContextFactory<...>` where `...` is the actual type of , but not generic T.

## How DbMigrator Doesn't Work

The problem is, the assembly instantiating `DbMigrator` has no access to the specific typed `IDbContextFactory<...>` that it needs to discover.  Also, my `DbContext` has no default constructor, and I don't want it to.  So I receive the exception `The target context '...' is not constructible.`

The thing that bothers me is, at the point I am instantiating `DbMigrator`, I already have an instance (or *may* already be *within* an instance) of the `DbContext` I am migrating.  Also, I have access to a generic `IDbContextFactory<T>` that is not discoverable by DbMigrator's internals, but I'd be happy to provide it an instance.

## The Question

So how do I tell DbMigrator to either just use my Context instance, or use an instance of a IDbContextFactory I specify?  When it relies on its magic juju behind the scenes to try to discover these things (presumably using reflection/ServiceLocation) it is failing.

## My Situation

Within one AppDomain, I am using `n` Contexts.  I'd like to say one, but it's typically two, and may be more than that.  So any solution that relies on a **single** app/web config property, or an attribute decorator, which points to a **single** DbConfiguration or ConnectionFactory won't work for me.  Because there can only be one per AppDomain and, unless I could configure it based contextually on which Context I'm needing at the time, it is futile.  So there's wiggle room there, but I dunno.

Also, there may be some juju I don't understand about EF relating to the `base` constructor.  But I don't believe passing a `DbConnection` into the constructor instead of a `nameOrConnectionString` would work.  It is still not an empty constructor.  But if there's something EF does to search for constructors with that, and how to utilize it, that MIGHT work.